# Azure Redis Cache: is it possible to connect to the cache in an integration test?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-redis-cache

I am running integration tests against an Azure Redis Cache. This is my very straightforward cache implementation:

```
public class RedisCacheEngine : ICacheEngine
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationService();
        var connectionString = config.Get("Redis.ConnectionString");
        var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
        return connection;
    });

    private static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection => LazyConnection.Value;

    public TValue Get<TValue>(string key) where TValue : class
    {
        var redisValue = Connection.GetDatabase().StringGet(key);
        return redisValue == RedisValue.Null 
            ? default(TValue) 
            : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TValue>(redisValue);
    }

    public void Set<TValue>(string key, TValue value) where TValue : class => 
        Connection.GetDatabase().StringSet(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));

    public void Remove(string key) => Connection.GetDatabase().KeyDelete(key);
}
```

When I look at the `connection` object in the debugger, its `failureMessage` field reads "SocketFailure on PING". I don't believe the server is timing out, as the timeout window is a generous five seconds and I'm on a fast system, with a fast connection.

The connection string is a standard Azure Redis Cache string, of the form

myapp.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=___,ssl=True,abortConnect=False

I have tried setting ssl = False, but without success.

I would ideally like to be able to run these tests on my build environment, but at the moment I can't retrieve a working connection. I can't see anything obvious that I may be missing in the documemtation. Are there any checks I can run to ensure I'm doing the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to connect to the cache in an integration test?

Yes, I do a demo with your mentioned code just using **connectionString** directly, it works correctly on my side.

```
 private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            var connectionString = "mytest.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=xxxxxxxx,ssl=True,abortConnect=False";
            var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
            return connection;
        });
```

According to exception message **SocketFailure on PING**, I assume that your development environment firewall which is blocking port **6379, 6380**.

If your redis service is **Premium pricing tier**, please have a check whether there is a firewall rule that blocks the client connection.

If your network is behind a firewall, please have a try to make sure the ports are open. Or please have a try to use another network environment.

[image]